# Parsing JSON to array not working when back button pressed

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm having some trouble with an issue in my Android Studio application that is to do with pressing the back button. Basically the user inputs into a text view and another method (not included as it works fine but I can post if requested) searches an API for the relevant data and displays it in a recycler view. Then the user makes a selection from the recycler view and the method below parses a JSON file and adds relevant data from it to an array in a separate class "Director". Once this happens the next activity "GraphActivity" starts and draws a number of nodes on a canvas for each director in the array.

The issue I am having is that when I make an input into the text view and then press the back button to close the soft keyboard on my Android device (it covers up the recycler view) and go through the steps I just mentioned, when the GraphActivity activity starts it does not work (no nodes are drawn). However, if I then press the back button to go back to the first activity and then make the same selection from the recycler view again, it works.

From what I can tell, the issue seems to be with the data being added to the "Director" array but I cannot figure out what is causing it, Logcat shows that the first time the GraphActivity activity starts the "Director" array is empty and therefore, no nodes are drawn but when I press back and then make the same selection again the array has the correct data and the nodes are drawn.

I would really appreciate some help with this as I am very new to Android Studio and have been searching around for hours to try and find a solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainAdapter.OnCompanyClickedListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView userInput;
    private Button search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    }

    //Parse JSON File
    public void searchCompanyDirectors(final String companyNumber){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            try{
                final String response = httpClient.run("myURL");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length();i++){
                                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                String appointment = o.getString("links");
                                String parsedAppointment = parseApp(appointment);

                                Director director = new Director(o.getString("name"),parsedAppointment);

                                Director.directorList.add(director);
                            }

                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
  }

    @Override
    public void onCompanyClicked(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this,Company.companyList.get(position).getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        chosenCompanyNumber = Company.companyList.get(position).getCompanyNumber();
        chosenCompany = Company.companyList.get(position).getTitle();
        searchCompanyDirectors(chosenCompanyNumber);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,GraphActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 }
```

The GraphActivity class:

```
public class GraphActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DrawGraph drawGraph;
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawGraph = new DrawGraph(this);
    setContentView(drawGraph);
```

The DrawGraph class:

```
public class DrawGraph extends View {

private Paint p1;
private Paint p2;
private Paint p3;
private Paint paint;

private Path path;
private Point point1;

private int radius = 300;
double x;
double y;
double angle;

int mWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int mHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

List<Director> directorList = Director.getDirectorList();
private String chosenCompany = MainActivity.getChosenCompany();
private static List<Float> ordinates = new ArrayList<>();

public DrawGraph(Context context) {
    super(context);
    p1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p1.setStrokeWidth(10);
    p2 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p2.setStrokeWidth(10);
    p3 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p3.setStrokeWidth(5);
    path = new Path();
    paint = new Paint();
    point1 = new Point(mWidth/2, mHeight/2);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // Colors
    p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p1.setColor(Color.RED);
    p2.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    p3.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p3.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(18f);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(chosenCompany, 0, chosenCompany.length(),bounds);

    //Draw company and directors
    for (int i = 1; i <= directorList.size(); i++)
    {
        //Divide the company node
        angle = i * (360/directorList.size());
        x = point1.x + radius * cos(angle);
        y = point1.y + radius * sin(angle);

        //Draw directors
        canvas.drawCircle((float)x,(float)y - (bounds.height() / 2), bounds.width() + 5,p2);
        canvas.drawText(directorList.get(i-1).getName(),(float)x,(float)y,paint);
    }
```

Comment: Your GraphActivity.class is not drawing a graph, right? Where\How are you sending the Director data to GraphActivity.class?

Comment: No the GraphActivity class calls a class that draws the graph, I will post both classes above

Comment: If it's helpful at all, i've tried outputting the director array in the searchDirectors method just under where they are added and it they are successfully being added, however when I do the same at the end of the method just under "thread.start()" the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found an issue in DrawGraph class noted here;

```
List<Director> directorList = Director.getDirectorList();
private String chosenCompany = MainActivity.getChosenCompany();
```

You should **not directly access the data objects of one activity from another**. The previous activity could be destroyed etc as per Android OS and its [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). You must think of it like *out of sight, out of memory*; which can cause the current activity to not be able to access the data in the previous one.

You'd need to properly send the parsed data from your JSON file, the variables List directorList and the String chosenCompany from your MainActivity to GraphActivity.

You can send data from one activity to another by adding it to the intent with which you call the next activity. The [Intent class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) has features to help you send a small amount of information via itself; called putExtra() and getExtra(). More about them [here](https://zocada.com/using-intents-extras-pass-data-activities-android-beginners-guide).

You will need to add those variable datasets through intent.putExtra and fetch them back in your other activity onCreate by using getExtras.

**Activity A    >> Intent call to Activity B + Data >>    Activity B**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will implement this and post back whether or not it solves the issue

Comment: Hey so I tried implementing this, however it did not solve the issue.

Comment: What issue did you run into?